# How to configure simple form classes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

Is it possible to make simple form add the field name to the wrapper classes?

That is, if I have `f.input :foo_bar_baz`, then I want the wrapper to be `<div class="foo_bar_baz string required">`.  Is this possible?

Ideally I'd like to turn off the generation of the `id` attribute on elements as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can subclass the `SimpleForm::FormBuilder` and add and remove attributes at will: https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#custom-form-builder

You can probably adapt this example to your needs: https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Attributes-filter